# How do I pass auth tokens around for temporary Web API access in MVC6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a website that has an API service that dumb clients use to get and submit data. I'm building it using ASP.NET MVC6 and EF7.

The service is still in a prototyping stage, however I'm currently using the `[Authorize]` attribute on controller classes and methods and the default User Manager found in the MVC6 template (ASP.NET Identity?). It works pretty well for the website itself and for the purposes for the prototype and testing I've simply put `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the API methods that I need to access from the unauthorized machines.

However I *think* I need to basically pass a session token to these dumb clients that last only x hours that they can use to submit with `GET` and `POST` requests so they can be pre-authorized without having to pass around some master user/pass.

Note: I'm fairly new to MVC6 and do not have full knowledge of how ASP.NET / MVC security is handled.